# Get total count with pagintion in strapi v4

Tags: filter, strapi

I am implementing pagination in strapi v4. I am using below query.

```
const favorites = await strapi.db.query("api::gem.gem").findMany({
   where: { id: { $in: user.favorites.map((f) => f.id) } },
   offset: page > 1 ? (page - 1) * pageSize : 0,
   limit: pageSize,
   orderBy: { [sort]: order ? order : "asc" },
});
```

I want to get the count of all records which satisfies the condition.

I have tried passing `withCount:true` and `count:true` but nothing worked.

Any help will be much appreciated!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is a function called `findWithCount()` which does what you need

```
const [entries, count] = await strapi.db.query('api::blog.article').findWithCount({
  select: ['title', 'description'],
  where: { title: 'Hello World' },
  orderBy: { title: 'DESC' },
  populate: { category: true },
});
```

source: https://docs.strapi.io/developer-docs/latest/developer-resources/database-apis-reference/query-engine/single-operations.html#findwithcount